# Rails has many through extra attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, has-many-through

I have the following relationships:

```
# Project
has_many :teammates
has_many :users, through: :teammates

# User
has_many :teammates
has_many :projects, through: :teammates

# Teammate
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

The teammate table has a "role" field telling what role the user has in the project.
This is how I save a teammate in the DB with the role:

```
project.teammates.create(:user => current_user, :role => 10)
```

So this is working. Now what I'd like to do is fetch all users from a particular project, with all users having a role field, telling what role they have in that project.

Would that be possible? I read some posts talking about adding an attribute_accessible to the user model, but that's not in rails 4 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874702/need-data-from-rails-join-table-has-many-through):

This works

```
has_many :users, -> { select('users.*, teammates.role as teammate_role') }, through: :teammates
```